# If $a$ is a member of a finite group, and $e$ is the identity, how can I prove that $a^n=e$ for some $n$?

Tags: group-theory

I'm doing some self-teaching on abstract algebra. One of the chapter's exercises is to prove that $a^n = e$ for some $n>0$.  I can't figure out how to do this. I know that if $a,b$ are in a group $G$, then $ax=b$ must have a single solution.  But I can't translate that into a proof of this hypothesis.  Any hints?

Reference: Fraleigh p. 49 Question 4.34 or p. 58 Question 5.49 in A First Course in Abstract Algebra

Comment: Well, what about $N = 0$? If that's not what you're looking for, then you're almost surely going to need the assumption that the group is finite; otherwise, it's not true.

Comment: You are probably forgetting the hypothesis that $G$ is *finite*. (There are infinite torsion groups, but in order to specify the property of being torsion we'd basically be specifying the desired conclusion, so we must be talking about finite groups.) This is important information. It means the sequence of powers eventually repeats, so one power of $a$ is equal to another power of $a$; if you write the equation describing that fact and cancel what do you get?

Comment: That makes sense!  The pigeon hole principle applies here.  If the group has K members, then A^N must equal A^M for some N,M.  Then I assume N > M with no loss of generality, and get A^N = A^M, so A^(N-M) = E.  Beautiful!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_subgroup

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you mean that the relevant group $G$ is finite, because otherwise the claim is very false (the integers, or the non-zero reals under multiplication give such examples). Suppose that there were no such $N$; then can you prove that all the elements of $\{a^1, a^2, a^3, \dots\}$ are distinct? And then use this to contradict the finiteness assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Take $2$ in the additive group over integer numbers. Then clearly there is a non-zero n such that $2n=0$, Oh wait there isn't. But what is the group is finite?

Consider the subgroup generated by the element $a$ of a finite group $G$,clearly this subgroup is also finite, then by the pidgeonhole principle (since there are infinite positive values n can take and only finite elements in the group) there must be $m> n$ such that $a^m=a^n.$ now let $l=m-n$ then $a^n=a^m=a^n*a^l\rightarrow a^n=a^n*a^l$ but then $a^l=e$

Comment: sorry, I meant integers.

Answer (score 1):

See p. 2 of this first-rate PDF http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/Math501/3ways.pdf